# Can't find Firebase's PhoneAuthProvider class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm working on adding a phone authentication login to my app, but my xcode just can't find the PhoneAuthProvider class. I have included

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
```

and the right pods installed

```
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod ‘Firebase/Core’
```

Any idea to why it's not available for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was because my Firebase pods were outdated, after updating them to the newest version I was able to use the class.

To update your Firebase pods, go to terminal and type in

```
pod update Firebase/Auth
```

I'm gonna leave it here as I've found a few similar questions without any answers.

Comment: If you're importing `Firebase` then I don't think you need to manually import `Firebase Auth`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem in creation or config project or app. You need just need go:

> project-> add another app

and redo all process that you can create app.

In my case that worked.

Note: don't create another project because Firebase only provide 3 project to create.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Project> Clean Build Folder. Build the project. This fixes my problem.

Comment: I also fixed my problem by `Project> Clean Build Folder` this. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to close whole XCode and then open it again, and everything worked fine.